# Flash Movie Won't Play Until page is refreshed

Tags: flash, page-refresh

A noob query! I have a self-loading-flash movie on a page which needs to load images and mp3 sounds having around 115k size. I'm using greensock platform(LoaderMax) to load the assets. When I open the HTML page in which this swf is embedded into in any browser(chrome, FF, IE) almost always I need to refresh the page for the swf to actually start playing. This is in spite of the progress bar confirming 100% successful download of required files.  If I don't refresh the page the movie doesn't play at all. So I'm currently using javascript to refresh the page once after 4 seconds of the initial pageload using cookie. But I hope there is some better method to do this such as reloading only the flash content or like so. Could you guys please suggest any better workaround to resolve the issue?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I dont know anything much about Flash but just in terms of general eventing it sounds like your movie actually starts to play before the content has downloaded. It might well be failing because the content hasn't downloaded; meanwhile the content keep merrily loading.

So when you refresh the page the content is pulled from cache and the movie plays as you would like. Id look for a call back event like "Loaded" and handle that once the content has finished downloading to start your movie playing.

See this Url for further advice:

[How to capture an event trigger when a flash movie successfully loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430928/how-to-capture-an-event-trigger-when-a-flash-movie-successfully-loaded)

> What i would do is use Actionscript 's ExternalInterface class that
>   allows your flash player to communicate with the javascript functions
>   available in the html file which contains the flash file. You could
>   have your flash file call a javascript function that triggers a
>   function that tells your javascript processing script that the flash
>   is ready. What is nice with this is that you get the exact level of
>   control you need over what should be loaded in the flash file when the
>   javascript takes over.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The greensock LoaderMax class has event handling methods like onProgress and onComplete. I've event handling functions for both these events and so I don't think that movie should start playing before the content is completely downloaded.I'm planning to use ExternalInterface class to pause the movie if any modal window is opened by the user. Will see if I can also use it to resolve this issue. Thanks once again!